# gcloud iam service-accounts keys create gives invalid jwt signature error

Tags: jwt, key, gcloud, service-accounts

Is there any difference between a key that I create using the gcloud iam command below vs. going thru the console to create a json key?  Each results in a .json file that other than obvious differences in the private_key_id and private_key values are identical.  Here are the gcloud commands I am using:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create my-sa-name
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project-id --member="serviceAccount:my-sa-name@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role="roles/owner"
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json --iam-account=serviceAccount:my-sa-name@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

However, when I try and leverage the one pulled down thru the command line, I get:

```
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature.', '{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT Signature."}')
```

Oddly if I go to the console, create a key for the same service account, and put the file that downloads to my computer in place of the one from the CLI, all works fine.

How am I using the key you ask?  I'm using the function-frameworks to locally run and debug a cloud function that will access a cloud storage bucket, so my code is using the google.cloud.storage client library (python 3.8).  I run the local process with the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS set to the location/filename of the json key file.  I know this all works fine b/c of the console-downloaded key working fine.

I have also tried using gcloud auth service-account --key-file=key.json and this also gives me the Invalid JWT Signature error.

Fortunately I'm not blocked b/c I can use the manually-created key, but I would REALLY like to automate every possible step here...

So... can anyone explain this?  Seen it, figured it out and know how to fix it?

Comment: No, there's no difference. What you're doing should work. Rereading.

Comment: Ah, the account value in `...keys create` does not get the `serviceAccount:` prefix

Comment: Should be `--iam-account="my-sa-name@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json \
--iam-account=my-sa-name@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

One way to clarify this is:

```sh
ACCOUNT="[[YOUR-ACCOUNT]]"
PROJECT="[[YOUR-PROJECT]]"
EMAIL="${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member="serviceAccount:${EMAIL}" \
--role="roles/owner"

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL} \
--project=${PROJECT}
```